# A regex that forbids certain characters at the end of a string

Tags: regex

Using RegEx to validate user input, I would like to match any string that starts with a letter, followed by 0 or more characters like so:

```
\A[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*
```

but which forbids hyphens and underscores as the last character in the string. How do I finish this RegEx?

Examples of matching strings:

```
a
a-b
ab_c--de
```

Examples of non-matching strings:

```
a-
abc-
a_
-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*(?:_|-)$)[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*$
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/33

Comment: I had a sense it was going to require familiarity with fancier "lookahead" constructs... Thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe which regex flavor are you using?we could use `lookbehind` as well

Comment: Ruby's Oniguruma (or is it Onigmo?)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it needs lookahead/behind. Does this work for you?

```
\A[a-z]([-_]*[a-z0-9])*\Z
```

Comment: I can't at all presume to be certain, @JonathanLeffler, but I think it's okay --- at least I haven't been able to come up with something that should match but doesn't. (I think because you can skip over the `[-_]*`, go right to the `[a-z0-9]`, and "loop back around" as it were.)

Comment: I've taken a second look and changed my mind; you're OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
\A([a-z][a-z\d_-]*[a-z\d]|[a-z])\Z
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qG0eN8/4)

Comment: I think you need an extra 0-9 range, as in: \A^([a-z][a-z0-9_-]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z]+)$\Z

Comment: also, why the + towards the end?